# Saber nombre de un Boton de una WEB

Tags: html, aplicación-web

Les queria preguntar si hay alguna forma de ver el nombre de un boton de una pagina web,ya que viendo el codigo HTML esta invible..no aparece "name".
Alguien conoce otro modo de saberlo ?[image: Adjunto les dejo la imagen del HTML donde no se encuentra el nombre :/]

Comment: Si no aparece es porque no tiene dicho atributo. Hasta donde yo sé el atributo **name** no tiene ningún valor por defecto, en otras palabras, en este caso no está definido.

Comment: Simplemente no existe el atributo name. Así fue programado.

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso puntual, DevTools (la herramienta que estás utilizando) es la forma más cercana a ver los atributos *en tiempo real*, o sea, después que JavaScript o algún otro método haya modificado los elementos en el DOM.

---

En este caso el atributo **name** no fue definido, y al no tener valor por defecto, simplemente no lo obtenemos si queremos acceder a él (obtenemos un valor de **null**.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('enviar').getAttribute('name'));
```

```html
<input id="enviar" type="submit" class="submit" value="Ingresar">
```

Answer (score 0):

La realidad es que todo navegador necesita acceder al código HTML para poder mostrar una página Web. Por lo tanto siempre habrá algún modo de poder verlo u obtenerlo.

En este caso, simplemente el que desarrollo la página no puso el atributo name en el input submit, es por eso que no es que no lo veas si no que no existe.

Comment: Y si deseo hacer un Login en VB NET como lo harian ustedes si no tienen el nombre de ese boton ???

Comment: Podrías realizar otra pregunta acerca de VB NET y con gusto expertos en el tema te podrán ayudar a lo que necesitas. Si no tienes más dudas aquí, sería buena idea que pusieras una respuesta como útil para ti, para que cuando alguien más tenga una duda similar, sea más fácil encontrarla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué alguien intentaría obtener el nombre del `input`? Lo que en realidad quiere es accionar la función que se ejecuta al hacer *click* en el botón **ingresar**.

Supongo que la solución es algo como esto.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit()
```

Pero antes habría que editar los campos de texto de texto para que no salga error de autentificación.

Answer (score 0):

Es un input tipo submit, el valor se obtiene de la siguiente forma:

```
document.getElementById('enviar').value
```

Asumiendo al input se le pone el id "enviar" de la siguiente forma:

```
<input id="enviar" type="submit" class="submit" value="Ingresar">
```